# What bracha is made on Seaweed?

Tags: blessing, food

If seaweed would be eaten by itself, what bracha is made on it?

It's defined as, "Large algae growing in the sea or on rocks below the high-water mark."
See Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seaweed) for more.
It's not considered by scientists to be a plant, then, which would presumably require the bracha "haadamah".

Comment: I'm guessing it's like mushrooms

Comment: Do we use scientific definitions to determine Berachoth?

Comment: @SethJ how do you determine brachos for a food that it's not obvious where it comes from or well known to most people? (or most frum Jews)

Comment: @Yehoshua, I dunno. But see: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3821/5

Comment: @DoubleAA It's not at all like mushrooms. Mushrooms do not use use photosynthesis, and instead decompose other plants for food. But seaweed IS a plant. Yehoshua: Why do you think it's not a plant? It certainly is. Seaweed do not have roots, and halachically that might be necessary to be called a plant, but scientifically a plant is defined by photosynthesis.

Comment: I should soften what I wrote. Some do not classify the red and brown seaweed as plants because they do not use chlorophyll but rather a different molecule. But I'm not convinced that chlorophyll is the halachic definition of haadama.

Comment: @Ariel I know mushrooms don't use photosynthesis. I think roots in the ground is a good possible definition for haadama and both mushrooms and algae can lack that.

Comment: @DoubleAA Then what about the plants in the Pleuston family, such as Duckweed? They float in water, and the roots just dangle freely. They are unquestionably plants.

Comment: @Ariel What about it? They'd probably also be Shehakol like mushrooms. Why do you keep talking as if the taxonomic category of Plantae is even remotely relevant?

Comment: @DoubleAA I never once said Plantae. I said the opposite: I'm not convinced that the scientific calssification is what counts. I was raising questions, not answering them. Does chlorophyll count? Do roots count? Deciding that can help in distinguishing brachas for mushrooms or duckweed. Don't forget about mistletoe which grows on a tree, not the ground, but is Ha'adama because its source is ultimately a living plant in the ground.

Answer (score 8):

According to these 2 links it is shehakol.

http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3089

http://www.dinonline.org/2011/06/14/berachah-on-seaweed/

Comment: Where did the internet get semicha from?

Comment: @DoubleAA AOL who in turn received it from the ArpaNet. This went back many doros to the chassidishe dynasty of Gore

Comment: @DoubleAA the ones answering at dinonline are people with smicha if it's worth anything

Comment: He says that seaweed is a type of algae, which is true. But why does he say that algae gets a shehakol? Hydroponic plants that grow in a container that is attached to the ground get a haadama after all.

Comment: @Ariel Isn't the definition of hydroponic that it grows in the air and not on the ground?

Answer (score 5):

Seaweeds are not considered to be plants. If you eat a whole of them by themselves without anything additional you should say "Shehakol".

It's in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 204 a. Seaweeds are like mushroom for this matter since they do not have roots in the ground, so although they are considerd to be plants kosher-wise (not meat), they are not considered to be fruits or vegetables Bracha-wise.