# Would there be any maaser derabbanan on hydroponically grown plants?

Tags: halacha, technology, agriculture, maaser-tithes

Related: [What bracha should be made on hydroponics/aeroponics?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52630/what-bracha-should-be-made-on-hydroponics-aeroponics)

This question was originally mentioned by [Rabbi Eliyahu Fink](http://finkorswim.com/) in his [Daf Yomi shiur (Shabbat 128)](http://daf.finkorswim.com/2013/02/07/shabbos-daf-128/).

He was talking about *tevel d'rabanan* -- food that requires tithing, but only rabbinically.

> It's a pot that's just self-sustaining. It could be suspended. Hydroponically, even. Maybe, i don't know, it's a little different. It's liquid, not dirt. Who knows. ([approximately 47 seconds into the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPAysWbck_I#t=47))

So, indeed, who knows? Or in Hebrew, mi yodeya? ;)

**Would hydroponically grown plants require *trumah and maaser derabbanan*?**

Comment: AFAIK hydroponically grown produce is not covered by Shemitta restirctions. Logically, therefore, I would expect that there is no requirement for maaser.

Answer (score 6):

The Star-K [cites](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/1121/hydroponics/) an argument about this between Rs [Tzvi Pesach Frank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzvi_Pesach_Frank) and [Yechiel Michel Tukachinsky](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99).

For extensive discussion, see Derekh Emunah ([Terumot 2:1 Beiur Halacha sv Ochel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49069&st=&pgnum=53)).