# Are plants that exhibit rapid plant movement considered non-Kosher animals?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, animals, agriculture, non-kosher-species

There is a [question here asking if sea sponges are Kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3821/1947). The answers seem to center around the idea that regardless of if they have animal cells, a halachic classification might depend on how it appears (and coral, for example, *vaguely look* like some sort of plant).

As a followup, are plants that exhibit [rapid plant movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_plant_movement) such as the venus flytrap, which have moving parts to eat insects considered to be animals in that they wouldn't be Kosher due to this characteristic?

Comment: Adnei Hasadeh(kilaiyim 8:5) half plant half person considered a chayah.

Comment: @sam Is there a way in which _adnei hasadeh_ are considered plants - biologically or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked [R' Natan Slifkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natan_Slifkin) this question by email, and he responded that no, rapidly-moving plants are not considered animals, as dictated by common sense.

Comment: I'm sure you have a lot of fun emailing people who have their own Wikipedia pages ;)

Comment: Does this include Triffids?

Comment: What are they instead?

Comment: Please source common sense.