# *Tzomeach* (צוֹמֵחַ) in kashrus halacha

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals, agriculture

To find the kashrus status of an organism, we first need to correctly classify it as *tzomeach*, animal, bird, or fish, as each group has its own distinct requirements. E.g., animals need to chew cud and have cloven hooves, while fish need (fins and) scales.

What is the halachic definition of a *tzomeach* (צוֹמֵחַ)?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30180/2

Comment: Are you going to ask about דומם too?

Comment: Are you going to ask about בהמה\חיה also, or shall I?

Comment: @Shokhet I am not going to. I assume it would be anything not in the other three categories. Furthermore, I don't see any questionable animals, only questionable plants (e.g. slime mold), birds (e.g. dinosaurs), and fish (e.g. penguins). Each of those would be animals if not that other thing.

Comment: @Shokhet Besides, I don't have a single Hebrew term to ask about. ;-)

Comment: @NBZ That's not entirely true. The Rambam, for instance, counts Sheretz HaAretz and Remes HaAretz as separate lavim, both separate from "non-kosher Behema and Chaya".

Comment: @NBZ There, I [asked it](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/what-defines-a-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%94). ;-)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3821